# PL/SQL: Passing an 'array' of strings as argument to sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

Using plsql, I want to run my test.sql multiple times, each time will pass in a different argument to test.sql and also spool that result to a different file.

The file name may not have a relation with the argument being passed.

I'm hoping I can define two 'arrays'; one for the filename to spool to, and the other for the argument value.

```
declare
my_types sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll := sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('typeA', 'typeB', 'typeC');
my_filenames sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll := sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('fileNameForA', 'fileNameForB', 'fileNameForC');
begin
  for r in my_types.first..my_types.last
  loop
    --dbms_output.put_line(my_types(r));
    --dbms_output.put_line(my_filenames(r));
        spool my_filenames(r)
    @test.sql my_types(r);
        spool off
  end loop;
end;
/
```

For the spool, it says that it encountered symbol `"MY_FILENAMES"` when it expected `:= . < @ % ;`. 
Also, it looks like `test.sql` is taking the argument I put in literally, so `'my_types(r)'` instead of the expected `'typeA'`. If there is a completely different and easier way of doing this in plsql then let me hear it. Thanks.

Comment: What is your `test.sql`? What is `my_filenames`? Where are you running this? `spool` is a SQL*Plus command...

Comment: @Ben `test.sql` is just a `select` statement that uses the argument in the `where` clause. `my_filenames` is a list of filenames to create when spooling. The first element in `my_filenames` should be the file created for running `test.sql` with the argument being the first element in `my_types`.

Comment: PL/SQL runs on the database server.  SQL*Plus is a client application that runs scripts located on the client.  You can't call SQL*Plus scripts from within PL/SQL, that doesn't make sense as an architecture.  You can't put SQL*Plus commands like `spool` in PL/SQL.  A PL/SQL block can generate files using `utl_file` but those files would exist on the database server not on the client.

Comment: I see. Then I guess this is more of a sqlplus question than a plsql question. Right, I will indeed be running this on sqlplus using a windows command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this to work (clunky, ugly), you have have to use the PLSQL to generate a sql scripts with calls to th esql script(s) you are trying to test. e.g.

```
set serveroutput on
spool run_it.sql
declare
   my_types sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll := sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('typeA', 'typeB', 'typeC');
   my_filenames sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll := sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('fileNameForA', 'fileNameForB', 'fileNameForC');
begin
  for r in my_types.first..my_types.last
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line('spool ' || my_filenames(r) );
    dbms_output.put_line('@test.sql ' || my_types(r) );
    dbms_out.put_line ('spool off' );
  end loop;
end;
/
spool off
@run_it.sql
```

Not tested/compiled. but I hope you get the idea.

With the above run_it.sql should look like:

```
spool fileNameForA
@test.sql typeA
spool off
spool fileNameForB
@test.sql typeB
spool off
.
.
```